# What is the easiest way to deeply clone (copy) a mutable Scala object?

Tags: scala, clone

What is the easiest way to deeply clone (copy) a mutable Scala object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you want the easiest way to deep copy a Scala object and not the fastest, you can always serialize the object, provided that it's serializable, and then deserialize it back.  The following code only runs when compiled, not in REPL.

```
def deepCopy[A](a: A)(implicit m: reflect.Manifest[A]): A =
  util.Marshal.load[A](util.Marshal.dump(a))

val o1 = new Something(...) // "Something" has to be serializable
val o2 = deepCopy(o1)
```

Comment: I did a little [test](https://gist.github.com/4409b8562ac24fc042b0) but I keep getting _ClassNotFoundException_ (and case classes are serializable).

Answer (score 7):

A Java-specific solution (which should work great in Scala too), is the [Cloner library](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning). It's fast, easy, deeply clones objects based on fields (using reflection), and is smart enough not to clone known immutable objects (like String, Integer, etc.). Finally, you can register custom immutable objects so it won't clone them either.

I highly recommend it.

Comment: First time I've heard of the Cloner library.  Sounds very handy!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Cloner library. Worked like a charm in my spark scala code.