# Deep copy of 2D array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, deep-copy

How do I do a deep copy of a 2D array in Scala?

For example

```
val a = Array[Array[Int]](2,3)
a(1,0) = 12
```

I want val b to copy values of a but without pointing to the same array.

Comment: Discussion of a similar topic can be found at: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267436/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-deeply-clone-copy-a-mutable-scala-object>

Comment: This is not valid code in your example.  Can you reformat?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `clone` method of the `Array` class. For a multi-dimensional `Array`, use `map` on the extra dimensions. For your example, you get

```
val b = a.map(_.clone)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just transpose it twice

```
a.transpose.transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
val a = Array[Array[Int]]
```

you could try:

```
for(inner <- a) yield {
  for (elem <- inner) yield {
    elem
  }
}
```

A deeper question is WHY you would want do do so with ints?  The whole point of using immutable types is to avoid exactly this kind of construct.

If you have a more generic `Array[Array[T]]`, then your main concern is how to clone the instance of `T`, not how to deep-clone the array.

Comment: Arrays in Scala are Java arrays and hence mutable.